# Struggling with python code to sort monthly data mean in chronological order

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am a relatively new user to Python and am having trouble with sorting daily timeseries data to monthly data in correct order using Pandas. I have a large daily dataset, e.g. snippet:

```
    Date    Current_BP  month   year
0   1/7/1895    76883.020   7   1895
1   2/7/1895    31387.660   7   1895
2   3/7/1895    14113.330   7   1895
3   4/7/1895    7587.465    7   1895
4   5/7/1895    5222.271    7   1895
```

I want to calculate a monthly average and used this code:

```
df=df.groupby(['year', 'month']).mean()
```

This gives the data like this:

```
year    month   Current_BP
1895    10      35154.870968
        11      8511.711567
        12  2190.365226
        7   12342.392387
        8   19052.299355
        9   26362.408667
1896    1   2000.000000
       10   10325.662645
       11   16764.958900
       12   2018.403677
```

The issue I have is that for plotting I need the monthly data in chronological order (ie. month 1-12 sorted for each year).

Comment: Have you tried `.sort_index()` ?

Comment: How did you create `month` and `year`?  It looks like pandas thinks those are strings instead of integers.  The order its showing you is the correct order for sorting strings.  If you change the columns to integers, it will work fine.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks I used this to split out the / symbol:   df[["day", "month", "year"]] = df["Date"].str.split("/", expand=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tim Roberts said, convert the column to integer:   df['month'] = df['month'].astype(int).  Otherwise, your string sort order is 1, 10, 11 before 2.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['7', '7', '7', '10', '12', '1'],
                   'Current_BP': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df['year'] = 1895

df2 = df.groupby(['year', 'month']).mean()   # wrong order

df['month'] = df['month'].astype(int)    # convert string to integer
df3 = df.groupby(['year', 'month']).mean()
print(df3)
#             Current_BP
# year month            
# 1895 1               6
#      7               2
#      10              4
#      12              5
```

Comment: Hi @Hammurabi, I think I am on the right track thanks to you and Tim's help but have now got this error "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer" .... there are some zeros in my dataset but don't think that is an issue?

Comment: Looks like some of your month values are null.  You can fill the column nulls with a value, but I think you won't want that because what month number would you use?  Maybe filter out rows with nulls?

Comment: I can't seem to see any nulls in data - here is link to it 
https://universityofadelaide.box.com/s/zc8olqtxkcls6gzg6pg1u1zfpfzq1vl6    and read code I used df=pd.read_csv('Barrage_Flow.csv', usecols=[0,1])

Comment: Inspect your data using unique_months = set(df['month'].tolist()).  What do you see in there?

Comment: Hi Hammurabi, thanks very much, here is list, there is a nan in there:  {nan, '9', '3', '5', '6', '7', '11', '1', '2', '4', '10', '12', '8'}....... I have looked back in csv and there seems to be an issue with dates before 1900 not being in date format in excel. This seems a fundamental issue in excel with handing pre-1900 dates, I will try saving as a text file and then importing into python that way and let you know later if that solves issue.

Comment: Issue solved thanks, I converted to day month year in excel to get around the pre_1900 date issue, then imported. Thank you